# LG Smart TV SDK emulator on Virtual Box doesn't starts

Tags: windows, sdk, virtualbox, lg, smart-tv

I'm new on LG smart TV apps. I've installed the SDK provided by LG (Oracle Virtual Box, Safari, Eclipse, sdk itself).

Now everything is running, but when I try to launch the emulator, a remote control is displayed, and on the virtualbox window, I see an error and no emulator is launched.

This is my plataform:
Windows 7 on a intel i7, 8 gb ram
Virtual Box 4.1.18 (I've installed 4.2.4 before, but sdk installer replace it to 4.1.18)
Safari 5.1.7
Java JRE 1.6
LG Smart TV SDK 3.0.0

This is the log generated by Virtual Box:

VirtualBox 4.1.18 r78361 win.amd64 (Jun  5 2012 15:58:23) release log

00:00:05.144 Log opened 2015-09-28T15:09:54.564361900Z

00:00:05.144 OS Product: Windows 7

00:00:05.144 OS Release: 6.1.7601

00:00:05.144 OS Service Pack: 1

00:00:05.144 Host RAM: 7926MB RAM, available: 864MB

00:00:05.144 Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe

00:00:05.144 Process ID: 12536

00:00:05.144 Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC

00:00:05.145 Installed Extension Packs:

00:00:05.145   None installed!

00:00:05.156 Power up failed (vrc=VINF_SUCCESS, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))

00:00:05.439 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb} aComponent={Console} aText={The virtual machine is not powered up}, preserve=false

Is there any known issue about this? What is the reason because "Power up failed"? How can I fix the VM? Does this software really works on Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: the error window from VirtualBox shows this error msg:

Fallo al abrir una sesión para la máquina virtual LG Smart TV Emulator 2013.

Failed to open release log (could not open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LG_Smart_TV_SDK\LG_Smart_TV_Emulator_2013\dhg74266z\Logs\VBox.log' (fOpen=0x322), VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).

Código Resultado: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Componente: Console
Interfaz: IConsole {1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb}

Answer (score 0):

I would try 4.2.18 and make sure you are installing the correct SDK for your OS (x64/x32).

You can uninstall VBox and reinstall if needed and again check your architecture